# Any git repo viewer that works over SSH?

Tags: linux, windows, git, user-interface, repository

so I have a folder of Git repositories on a Linux(Ubuntu) box that I can only access via commandline SSH. I mainly work on Windows and I want to find a way to look at the list of repositories on Windows via some sort of GUI, I tried using Gitlist,http://gitlist.org/, but I'm not sure how to access the localhost of the Ubuntu machine from my Windows machine.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs can display git logs with their graph structure in text mode. Just start `emacs`, type <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>, type in the path and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. In the status buffer, just press <kbd>l</kbd> to view the log.

BTW, if you know no Emacs: use <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd> to end Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution which also can be used for other programs than git viewers might be a X-Server for Windows like [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/).

With that installed you can start any X program from the ssh shell if X display forwarding is active. The X program is then displayed on your Windows screen.